# issue in passign hash values across objects in ruby onr rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am running into problems passing a hash (serialized as a hash) to a newly created object.  The values get converted to yaml format.

Consider the following:

```
Model ComputerUser:

...
serialize preferences  
'#in the database I see the following "{0=>{color:red format:html}}"

    ....

   @computer_user.registrations.build(:user_pref => :preferences}.save 
   @computer_user.user_pref;
```

'#the above statement spills out the data in yaml format and that is how it gets persisted in the db.

Now, if I do the following from rails console, I don't see the same issue, i.e. the hash is stored as a hash and not converted to the yaml format.  I see the following when I inspect the value of the column in the new object:

```
=>{0=>{color:red format:html}}
```

Please note that I have used serialize for the attributes in the source as well as the target.   Things seem to work from the console but just note from the controller! Any ideas what is going on?  Why is the issue occurring only in the web application and not on the console.

Comment: The code, as posted, would cause several syntax errors. Please take some time to edit your post, copying and pasting your actual model code and formatting it more carefully. Once you've done that it will be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Jordan - I posted out the details late last night in a rush hoping that someone might know the issue and might be able to help. But yes I do realize now that the sample description might have not been helpful for other readers.  Point taken.  I went ahead and put the  sample together.  And I found the solution too.. I will post it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not using instance variables for assignment.

If you have "serialize, Hash" declared in both classes, this is how you need to build the child object from the parent:

```
    @computer_user.registrations.build(:user_prefs => @computer_user.preferences).save
```

That works like a charm.